# How to sum two totals with SetInverval()?

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck for 2 days in a problem. I would like to sum the total of btc and atom variation and display it.

[image]

So for the example on the picture => -0.09 + 0.00 = -0.09

I want to display on `<p><span id="total"></span></p>` the value -0.09.

With `SetInterval()`, I don't understand how to I can sum the 2 values (-0.09 and 0.00)?

JS

```
console.clear();

/////// BITCOIN ///////
let wsBtc = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');

let btcStockPriceElement1 = document.getElementById('btcValue1');
let btcStockPriceElement2 = document.getElementById('btcValue2');

let btcLastPrice = null;
let btcStockObject = null;

wsBtc.onmessage = (event) => {
  btcStockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
};

let btc1 = 0,
  btc2 = 0;
let btcVariation = 0;

let btcRunTimers = setInterval(() => {
  let minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  if (minutes === 25) {
    let val1 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement1.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement1.style.color =
      !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > btcLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc1 = val1;
  }

  if (minutes === 30) {
    let val2 = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(btcStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    btcStockPriceElement2.innerText = price;
    btcStockPriceElement2.style.color =
      !btcLastPrice || btcLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > btcLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    btcLastPrice = price;
    btcStockObject = null;

    btc2 = val2;

    btcVariation = ((parseFloat(btc2) - parseFloat(btc1)) / btc1) * 100;

    document.getElementById('btcResult').innerHTML = btcVariation.toFixed(2);
  }
}, 60000);

/////// ATOM ///////

let wsAtom = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/atomusdt@trade');

let atomStockPriceElement1 = document.getElementById('atomValue1');
let atomStockPriceElement2 = document.getElementById('atomValue2');

let atomLastPrice = null;
let atomStockObject = null;

wsAtom.onmessage = (event) => {
  atomStockObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
};

let atom1 = 0,
  atom2 = 0;
let atomVariation = 0;

let atomRunTimers = setInterval(() => {
  let minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
  if (minutes === 25) {
    let val1 = parseFloat(atomStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(atomStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    atomStockPriceElement1.innerText = price;
    atomStockPriceElement1.style.color =
      !atomLastPrice || atomLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > atomLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    atomLastPrice = price;
    atomStockObject = null;

    atom1 = val1;
  }

  if (minutes === 30) {
    let val2 = parseFloat(atomStockObject.p).toFixed(1);
    let price = parseFloat(atomStockObject.p).toFixed(1);

    atomStockPriceElement2.innerText = price;
    atomStockPriceElement2.style.color =
      !atomLastPrice || atomLastPrice === price
        ? 'black'
        : price > atomLastPrice
        ? '#AAFF00'
        : 'red';

    atomLastPrice = price;
    atomStockObject = null;

    atom2 = val2;

    atomVariation = ((parseFloat(atom2) - parseFloat(atom1)) / atom1) * 100;

    document.getElementById('atomResult').innerHTML = atomVariation.toFixed(2);
  }
}, 60000);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Crypto</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Total variance BTC & ATOM => <span id="total"></span></p>
    <div class="container mt-3">
      <h2>BITCOIN :</h2>
      <hr />
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="table-success">
          <tr class="text-center">
            <th>01h00</th>
            <th>02h00</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr class="text-center">
            <td><span id="btcValue1"></span></td>
            <td><span id="btcValue2"></span></td>
            <td><span id="btcResult"></span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr />
      <h2>ATOM :</h2>
      <hr />
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="table-success">
          <tr class="text-center">
            <th>01h00</th>
            <th>02h00</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr class="text-center">
            <td><span id="atomValue1"></span></td>
            <td><span id="atomValue2"></span></td>
            <td><span id="atomResult"></span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-3xdsjn?file=index.html).

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. The values in the HTML are coming from somewhere; they can either be summed from the data (IMO preferable) or by retrieving the DOM values and parsing. Doing it in a `setInterval` is the same, just over and over.

Comment: I would combine the two `setInterval()` calls into a single function that processes both ATOM and BITCOIN. Then at the end, it adds the two values and displays that in `TOTAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another `setInterval()` to get the contents of the two result fields, add them together, and put the sum in the `Total` field.

```
setInterval(function() {
    let btcResult = parseFloat(document.getElementById("btcResult").textContent);
    let atomResult = parseFloat(document.getElementById("atomResult").textContent);
    let total = btcResult + atomResult;
    document.getElementById("total").textContent = total.toFixed(2);
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Waaaaawww thank you a lot Barmar it works !!!!! :-)